# pyspark3 serializable filesystem

Tags: python, pyspark, hdfs

all - pyspark noob question here

am trying to create a list of files from hdfs directory and check their existance - this is a prototype for additional work. however i think the loop is pushing the execution from the driver to executor, and therefore, hadoop configuration is not available.

i need to find correct syntax in pyspark to serialize the fs and push this information to the executor, but not sure of the syntax.

does anyone have any guidance on this?

code is as follows:

```
nn_url            = "hdfs://ccycloud-1.mr-x.root.hwx.site:8020/"
date_str          = "20230711"
data_directory    = "/rs_stats/data/reg/"
archive_directory = "/rs_stats/archive/reg/"
fs                = sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())
Path              = sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
status            = fs.listStatus(Path("%s/date_str=%s" % (data_directory,date_str)))
for fstat in status:
      frompath = fstat.getPath()
      print("frompath:%s" % (frompath))
      fs.exists(Path(frompath))
```

output of pyspark session below - you can see that the "frompath:" print works, so the filepath is correctly found, but when i try to perform any fs operation on it, error - i believe this is due to lack of fs serialization to enable executor to perform the operation, but not sure of the syntax - that i think is the missing code here.

thanks in adv for any advice you can provide, mr

```
Using Python version 3.6.8 (default, Aug 13 2020 07:46:32)
Spark context Web UI available at http://ccycloud-1.mr-x.root.hwx.site:4041
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = yarn, app id = application_1691189915579_0015).
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>> nn_url            = "hdfs://ccycloud-1.mr-x.root.hwx.site:8020/"
>>> date_str          = "20230711"
>>> data_directory    = "/rs_stats/data/reg/"
>>> archive_directory = "/rs_stats/archive/reg/"
>>> fs                = sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())
>>> Path              = sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
>>> status            = fs.listStatus(Path("%s/date_str=%s" % (data_directory,date_str)))
>>> for fstat in status:
...       frompath = fstat.getPath()
...       print("frompath:%s" % (frompath))
...       fs.exists(Path(frompath))
... 
frompath:hdfs://ccycloud-1.mr-x.root.hwx.site:8020/rs_stats/data/reg/date_str=20230711/part-00000-00c34c42-de0d-45cd-baa2-4724246e8ef1.c000.snappy.parquet
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK3-3.3.0.3.3.7180.0-274-1.p0.31212967/lib/spark3/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1586, in __call__
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK3-3.3.0.3.3.7180.0-274-1.p0.31212967/lib/spark3/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 190, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK3-3.3.0.3.3.7180.0-274-1.p0.31212967/lib/spark3/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 332, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Constructor org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path([class org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getConstructor(ReflectionEngine.java:179)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getConstructor(ReflectionEngine.java:196)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:237)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```